# How to check if files are still created?

Tags: python, file

I would like to make a script to check whether or not files are still being created inside a folder. We can consider for our problem that there are no more files being created if let's say for 5 sec the list of files present in that folder remains unchanged. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inotifywait` to watch for events on a file or a directory.

```
inotifywait -m -e create /path/to/your/dir
```

It will show you the events and exits if no more event happens after 5 seconds.

```
inotifywait --timeout 5 -qm -e create /path/to/your/dir
```

By default it will use 5 seconds but you can change it by putting `--timeout` a

Comment: It doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

By created I'm assuming you mean existing, anyway to do that:

```
import os
entries = os.listdir('my_directory/')
```

then check length of entries with `len(entries)`

Comment: I corrected my phrase. not created, files are being created.